# Ubuntu Suspends Itself

Tags: 22.04, suspend, crash

I have this strange problem: my laptop suspends itself randomly when I use it normally.

- Journalctl (output below) says that I press the suspend key, but I'm sure I don't. I connect my laptop to an external monitor, keyboard, and mouse, so I'm sure I don't press the power button by mistake. I also disabled my internal laptop keyboard.
- This suddenly happened today, but I don't remember doing anything (update, upgrade, etc.) yesterday or even the day before it.
- The crash log (output below) doesn't give me anything useful.
- I found similar problem [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2018584).
- For now, I'm trying to disable suspend entirely using `sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`. It's been two hours and I can use my laptop like normal, but I still want to know what's the possible cause for this problem in case the current solution doesn't work.

Below is the events around the time my laptop was suspended (around 18:26). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### Output for `sudo journalctl --since="-5 minutes"`

```
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd-logind[840]: Suspend key pressed.
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD gnome-shell[2201]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD gnome-shell[2201]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD gnome-shell[2201]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD gnome-shell[2201]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD gnome-shell[2201]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD gnome-shell[2201]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD gnome-shell[2201]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD gnome-shell[2201]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD gnome-shell[2201]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd-logind[840]: Suspend key pressed.
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431562.9637] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD ModemManager[929]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431562.9637] device (enp3s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-st>
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431562.9737] device (00:66:19:66:50:A5): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', >
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431562.9739] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-i>
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431562.9741] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431562.9743] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-sta>
Sep 11 18:26:02 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD dbus-daemon[810]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatche>
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD dbus-daemon[810]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD kernel: wlo1: deauthenticating from 2e:40:8f:77:9c:fd by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD rtkit-daemon[1316]: Supervising 10 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD rtkit-daemon[1316]: Successfully made thread 27497 of process 1810 owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD rtkit-daemon[1316]: Supervising 11 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD wpa_supplicant[851]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=2e:40:8f:77:9c:fd reason=3 locally_generated=1
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD wpa_supplicant[851]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431563.1543] device (wlo1): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface->
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD avahi-daemon[804]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::45cd:9bd3:e687:db19 on wlo1.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD avahi-daemon[804]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv6 with address fe80::45cd:9bd3:e687:db19.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD avahi-daemon[804]: Interface wlo1.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431563.1696] dhcp4 (wlo1): canceled DHCP transaction
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431563.1697] dhcp4 (wlo1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431563.1697] dhcp4 (wlo1): state changed no lease
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD avahi-daemon[804]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.253.187 on wlo1.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD avahi-daemon[804]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlo1.IPv4 with address 192.168.253.187.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD avahi-daemon[804]: Interface wlo1.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD gnome-shell[2201]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431563.1731] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd-resolved[606]: wlo1: Bus client set default route setting: no
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD NetworkManager[811]: <info>  [1694431563.1735] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-sta>
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd-resolved[606]: wlo1: Bus client reset DNS server list.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD wpa_supplicant[851]: p2p-dev-wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD wpa_supplicant[851]: p2p-dev-wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD wpa_supplicant[851]: nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd-logind[840]: Suspend key pressed.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD suspend[27512]: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD logger[27512]: <13>Sep 11 18:26:03 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "136"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "97"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event12 - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "60"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event19 - Video Bus: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "106"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event20 - Video Bus: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "59"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "55"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "51"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event6  - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "53"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event17 - ELAN1200:00 04F3:30BA Mouse: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "114"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event18 - ELAN1200:00 04F3:30BA Touchpad: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "98"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event5  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "61"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "61"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event7  - Logitech MX Master 2S: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "132"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (**) Option "fd" "132"
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) event8  - Keychron K3: device removed
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: Finished Record successful boot for GRUB.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: Starting GRUB failed boot detection...
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: grub-initrd-fallback.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: Finished GRUB failed boot detection.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD wpa_supplicant[851]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD wpa_supplicant[851]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD wpa_supplicant[851]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlo1 disabled_11b_rates=0
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:70
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:72
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:81
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:83
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:71
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:76
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:84
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[1899]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:82
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd-sleep[27525]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.013 seconds
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD acpid[802]: client 1899[1000:1000] has disconnected
Sep 11 18:26:03 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD acpid[802]: input device has been disconnected, fd 23
```

---

### Output for `ls -al /var/crash`

```
total 13220
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie    4096 Sep 11 13:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root        4096 Feb 23  2023 ..
-rw-r-----  1 hana     whoopsie 3349325 Sep 11 06:53 _opt_microsoft_msedge_msedge.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 hana     whoopsie   99434 Sep  8 12:24 _usr_bin_blueman-applet.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 hana     whoopsie  100677 Sep  8 12:21 _usr_bin_blueman-manager.1000.crash
-rw-rw-r--  1 hana     whoopsie       0 Sep  8 12:21 _usr_bin_blueman-manager.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie      37 Sep  8 12:21 _usr_bin_blueman-manager.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1 hana     whoopsie 7230416 Sep  7 19:25 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 hana     whoopsie 2730450 Sep 11 13:59 _usr_bin_update-notifier.1000.crash
```

---

### My Spec

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
Kernel: 6.2.0-32-generic
```

---

Comment: Does it happen frequently or has it happened only once?

Comment: Never happened before today, but it happens quite often today. Sometimes even 3-4 times in 5 minutes.

Comment: Try not using it today, and try it tomorrow. Sometimes there could be some issues at the moment. If the issue still persists, try `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. If it still persists, let me know here.

Comment: Yesterday, even after disabling the suspend entirely, the "Suspend Key Pressed" event still persists. However, the suspend didn't happen because it's been masked.

`Sep 11 22:10:53 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd-logind[840]: Suspend key pressed. Sep 11 22:10:53 hana-TUF-Gaming-FX505GD systemd-logind[840]: Unit suspend.target is masked, refusing operation.`

Comment: As of today, based on `journalctl` output, there's no "Suspend Key Pressed" event anymore.

Comment: Good to know, problem solved.